# CMakeList file to generate LLVM bitcode file from C source file

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to generate LLVM bytecode file from a C source file (hello.c) using CMake. And below is my CMakeLists file.

```
###### CMakelists.txt ############
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-emit-llvm")

project (hello)
add_executable(hello hello.c)
```

1. I am new to CMake and not sure if this is the right way. I could not find any rules to make *.bc in the generated MakeFile
   . Please correct me here. I also tried "-save-temps"
2. Considering this for a single .c file. It would be really helpful if you could give me some hints on generating the same for a complete C project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you ultimately want is to be able to build a C-program
project with CMake and clang in which source files are compiled to LLVM bitcode
and the executable is linked from the bitcode files.

With CMake, asking clang to to link bitcode files means asking it to link in [LTO mode](https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html),
with the `-flto` linkage option.

And you can get clang to *compile* to LLVM bitcode with the `-flto` compilation
option, or with the `-emit-llvm` option.

For illustration here is a Hello World project comprising two source files and one header:

```
$ ls -R
.:
CMakeLists.txt  hello.c  hello.h  main.c
```

Here is the:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project (hello)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-flto")
add_executable(hello main.c hello.c)
target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -flto)
#target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -emit-llvm)
```

It will work equally well with:

```
#target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -flto)
target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -emit-llvm)
```

Make a build directory for CMake and go there:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
```

Generate the build system:

```
$ cmake ..
```

Build:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.c.o
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable hello
[100%] Built target hello
```

You will not find any `*.bc` targets in the Makefiles, nor any `*.bc` files
generated:

```
$ egrep -r '.*\.bc'; echo Done
Done
$ find -name '*.bc'; echo Done
Done
```

because the compilation option `-flto` or `-emit-llvm` results in an output
file:

```
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.c.o
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
```

that adheres to the usual CMake naming convention but is in fact not an *object file*
but an LLVM bitcode file, as you see:

```
$ file $(find -name '*.o')
./CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o: LLVM IR bitcode
./CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.c.o:  LLVM IR bitcode
```

The program does the usual thing:

```
$ ./hello 
Hello World!
```

**Later**

> When I try " make hello.o " it should generate the object file right?
>   the cmd executes successfully but, could not find the generated object file. Am I doing it right?

You are doing it in one way that is right, though not the only way that is right, but
your expectations are wrong. Look again at:

```
$ file $(find -name '*.o')
./CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o: LLVM IR bitcode
./CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.c.o:  LLVM IR bitcode
```

You can see there that the `.o` files that are made from `hello.c` and `main.c`
by the CMake-generated makefile are not called `hello.o` and `main.o` but `hello.c.o`
and `main.c.o`. CMake prefers a compiled filename to preserve the extension of the
source file, and append `.o`. That is a fairly common practice. So if you wanted
to use the makefile to compile `hello.c`, the most obviously right way would be
`make hello.c.o`.

Let's see what actually happens. In my CMake build directory:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1 hello.c.o
make -f CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
make[1]: 'CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
```

There was nothing to be done, because my `hello.c.o` was up to date. So I'll
delete it and repeat:

```
$ rm CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
$ make VERBOSE=1 hello.c.o
make -f CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
clang   -flto -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o   -c /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/hello.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
```

Now it has been recompiled.

However, because many people - like you - would expect `hello.o` to be compiled
from `hello.c`, CMake helpfully defines `hello.o` as a [`.PHONY` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)
that depends on `hello.c.o`:

```
$ egrep  -A3 'hello.o.*:.*hello.c.o' Makefile 
hello.o: hello.c.o

.PHONY : hello.o
```

So in fact I can do:

```
$ rm CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
$ make VERBOSE=1 hello.o
make -f CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
clang   -flto -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o   -c /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/hello.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
```

`make hello.o` is another way of making `hello.c.o`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried and got error related to gold linker. 
" error loading plugin: /usr/bin/../lib/LLVMgold.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory " I am working on it But, 
When I try " make hello.o " it should generate the object file right? the cmd executes successfully but, could not find the generated object file.. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Thank You Sir, I understood that. I want to request you for one more help. The main goal is to generate a single whole-program LLVM bitcode file. And LLVMgold has to be excluded. So now we have the bitcode files, what to add in CMakelists.txt so that it uses llvm-link to generate a final bitcode file linking those previous ones. 

Could you please help me with this ? Thank you

Comment: @manojh93 Sorry, on Stackoverflow you cannot keep on rolling a question into new questions. See
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
If you have problem beyond the original question that you can't solve yourself, you
should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that using the `-emit-llvm` flag does not produce a final binary and stops the configuration tests that CMake performs once that flag is used in them.

Apart from what's already been written about using the [LTO](https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html) infrastructure, you have 3 (or 2 and a half) other alternatives.

One is to use [Whole-Program LLVM](https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm) and use the commands provided to extract the relevant bitcode parts.

The other is to go the manual way of setting up custom targets (see [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) and [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)) on your CMake binary targets, that will get triggered on changes and will reproduce the desired outcome as if executed manually on the command line each time.

Now, on this last point, I had a similar need so I created a CMake project that provides that functionality ([llvm-ir-cmake-utils](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils)), but allows you to hook up those custom targets on existing ones as you please and see fit without having to rewrite everything from scratch each time.

There are examples in the repo, but in short, it allows you to attach custom targets on already existing CMake targets, e.g.

```
[...]
add_executable(qux ${SOURCES})

[...]
# this will create a bitcode generating target 
# and allow it to depend on the initial target in order to detect source code changes
llvmir_attach_bc_target(qux_bc qux)
add_dependencies(qux_bc qux)
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

After make,

```
$>file CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o
CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

if
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-emit-llvm")

written before

```
project (hello)
```

In order to obtain IR bitcode, I wrote:

```
###### CMakelists.txt ############
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (hello)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-flto")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-flto")
add_executable(hello hello.c)
target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -flto)
```

I worked several hours in order to have a Makefile working to compile from IR
code to native using lld, then with cmake it was much more faster.
Then reading at cmake generated Makefile, I was able to correct my Makefile:

```
clang  -flto  -flto <hello.c.o> ..
```

this worked but I do not know why -flto is written twice.

Thanl you very much for this post, showing clang as the centralized front end to various llvm provided commands.