# Callgraphs using GraphViz with CMake and Clang

Tags: c++, cmake, graphviz

My goal is to generate call graphs using CMake + Clang + GraphViz at build time.

Using these [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458738/create-a-call-graph-for-a-file-with-clang), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373814/8277897)] processes I can create simple graphs. But, I'm not sure how to generalise the process to a CMake project.

I have an executable target.

```
add_executable(${TARGET} ${SOURCES})
```

Which from within a macro, I add the graph relevant options to the target:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE -S -emit-llvm)
```

And, add an addtional post build command which generates the call graphs:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${TARGET}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMENT "Running clang OPT"
    COMMAND opt -analyze -dot-callgraph
)
```

But the clang attempts to create an executable for the target.
This results in this error:

```
[build] lld-link: error: 
Container.test.cpp.obj: unknown file type
```

I also don't understand how any custom command (`opt` for example) would access the produced LLVM representation. It doesn't look like my custom command has any knowledge of the relevant files (even if the above error was fixed).

---

What I understand so far:

1. CMake `add_executable` adds the `-o outfile.exe` argument to clang, this prevents me from doing the same steps shown in the linked processes [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458738/create-a-call-graph-for-a-file-with-clang), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373814/8277897)]
2. `$<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET}>` can be used to find the produced files from clang, but I don't know if this works for LLVM representation.
3. I've tried doing a custom target instead, but had issues getting all the `TARGET` sources with all the settings into the custom target.
4. The process outlined here [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957981/emitting-a-single-ir-bitcode-file-with-llvm-lld-using-cmake)] might be relevant specially `-Wl,-save-temps` but this seems to be a pretty roundabout way to get IR (using llvm-dis).
5. The `unknown file type` error is due to the object actually being `LLVM` representation, but I suspect the linker expects a different format.
6. To get the linker to understand `LLVM` representation, add `-flto` to the linker options `target_link_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE -flto)`, (source [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864924/cmakelist-file-to-generate-llvm-bitcode-file-from-c-source-file)]).
   This is awesome, because it means I've almost solved this... I just don't know how to get the path to the produced bitcode output files in cmake, once I do, I can pass them to opt (I hope...).
7. To get the target objects the following cmake command can be used `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${TARGET}>` in the case of cmake this will list the `.o` (Is the `.o` because of a rename by cmake?) LLVM bitcode files.
8. The `.o` file in this case is bitcode, however the `opt` tool appears to only a llvm representation. To convert to this `llvm-dis bitcode.bc –o llvm_asm.ll`. Due to cross compilation I believe the mangled symbol are of a strange format. Passing them into `llvm-cxxfilt` does not succeed, for example `llvm-cxxfilt --no-strip-underscore --types ?streamReconstructedExpression@?$BinaryExpr@AEBV?$reverse_iterator@PEBD@std@@AEBV12@@Catch@@EEBAXAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z`
9. So addressing 8. this is a MSVC name mangling format. This indicates that when compiling on windows clang uses the MSVC format name mangling. A surprise to me... (source [[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159432/msvc-c-name-mangling-from-string-on-runtime)]).
10. LLVM ships with `llvm-undname` it is able to demangle the symbols. This tool when I run it errors significantly when I give it raw input, it seems to only work with correct symbols. The tool `demumble` appears to be a cross platform, multi-format wrapper of llvm-undname and llvm-cxxfilt.

11.My almost working cmake macro is as follows:

```
macro (add_clang_callgraph TARGET)
    if(CALLGRAPH)
        target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE -emit-llvm)
        target_link_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE -flto)
        
        foreach (FILE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${TARGET}>)
            add_custom_command(
                TARGET ${TARGET}
                POST_BUILD
                COMMAND llvm-dis ${FILE}
                COMMAND opt -dot-callgraph ${FILE}.ll
                COMMAND demumble ${FILE}.ll.callgraph.dot > ${FILE}.dot
            )
        endforeach()
    endif()
endmacro()
```

However, this doesn't work... The contents of `${FILE}` is always the entire list...

This is still the case here:

```
foreach (FILE IN LISTS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${TARGET}>)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${TARGET}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND echo ${FILE}
    )
endforeach()
```

The result looks like:

```
thinga.obj;thingb.obj
```

This is because CMake doesn't evaluate the generator expression until AFTER the for loop is evaluated. Meaning, there is only one loop here and it contains the generator expression (not a resolved generator expression) (source [[6](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2018-August/068149.html)]). This means I cannot loop through object files and create a series of custom commands for each object file.

---

I'll add to the above as I find things out, If I figure out the whole process I'll post a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been a great pain in the arse.

---

What I'm hoping for, a way to make CMake accept building an executable to a single LLVM representation file, using that file with opt to get the callgraph and then finishing the compilation with `llc`.
I'm a little constrained though, as I'm cross compiling. Ultimately anything equivlient will do...

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils) project. Regarding the above and talking from experience, I'd say maybe use something like https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm or LTO to get the whole bitcode, but since you're cross-compiling you might be indeed restricted. In theory, they should work till the bitcode extraction.

Comment: In theory, they should work till the bitcode extraction. Can you not combine the LTO .o files (essentially bitcode) with a custom post-build rule using `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${TARGET}>`? Also, aren't you suppose to stop the compilation with `-c`? Lasltly, `opt` accepts both .bc and .ll format files. I'm not sure why you care suddenly about name mangling from point 8 onwards or what has it do with all the rest. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nah I actually want it to compile too, this is compile and graph (I hope...) :)

Comment: But regarding the name mangling, its part of the graphvis goal, to have a readable graph.

Comment: Hmm, well the demangling can happen anytime after, I don't see why to put in it with CMake or the compilation pipeline. `-emit-llvm` does not work for linking to object code, the error Clang emits is `error: -emit-llvm cannot be used when linking`. This is without the `-c` or `-S` flags. Up to this point, the fact that you're cross-compiling should not be relevant.

I'm the author of [this](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils) BTW, and I use LTO or gllvm whenever I can get away with it. However you get the bitcode files, you can collate them in a single bitcode with `llvm-link`.

Comment: `llvm-link` is a good idea thanks :)

Comment: `-emit-llvm` seems to be able to be used with the compiler if `-flto` is specified in the linker. It compiles atleast, perhaps it shouldn't?

Comment: Yeah, LTO is a different use case. If you provide a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` it'd be useful.

Comment: I added my macro :)
It *should* work with other projects... And by work, I mean fail the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt an answer just to gather all my comment responses so far.

If you want to "subvert" CMake, it can be done with something like this (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864924/cmakelist-file-to-generate-llvm-bitcode-file-from-c-source-file) out of OP's point 4 above):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

project(hello)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-flto")

add_executable(hello main.c hello.c)

# decide your bitcode generation method here
# target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -emit-llvm)
target_compile_options(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -c -flto)

# this is just to print
add_custom_target(print_hello_objs 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<JOIN:$<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello>," ">)

# this does some linking
# fill in details here as you need them (e.g., name, location, etc.)
add_custom_target(link_hello_objs 
  COMMAND llvm-link -o foo.bc $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello> 
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

For uses where processing on each file is required, the `COMMAND` can be an external script (bash/python) that just takes that list and generates the .dot files. The problem with generator expressions is that they are not evaluated till generation time in CMake and not in a `foreach` context.

If you want to trigger regeneration based on what object/bitcode file is recompiled, things get tricky since CMake has preset ways to invoke the components of a toolchain (compiler, link, etc.), hence why I wrote my [CMake-based project](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils) back then, but I'd strongly recommend avoiding overengineering at the start since it sounds as if you're not sure what you're up against yet.

I haven't bothered with making [LTO](https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html) work fully, in order to also get a working executable since I don't have such a setup on this machine ATM.

All the other requirements (e.g., Graphviz output, demangling) can be hooked up with further custom targets/commands.

Other solutions might be:

1. [gllvm](https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm)
2. for the desperate [llvm-ir-cmake-utils](https://github.com/compor/llvm-ir-cmake-utils)

Comment: Yup that works :)
Although I'm starting to think merging the llvm asm files was a bad plan... The graph is a little large lol. Any idea how to run opt once for each object file?

Comment: The `COMMAND` can be an external script (bash/python) that just takes that list and generates the .dot files. The problem with generator expressions is that they are not evaluated till generation time in CMake and not in a `foreach` context. If you wanna trigger regeneration based on what object/bitcode file is recompiled, things get tricky, hence why I wrote my CMake-based project back then, but I'd strongly recommend avoiding overengineering at the start since it sounds as if you're not sure what you're up against yet.

Comment: Looks like I was able to do what I wanted with an external script pretty easily. What did you mean by subvert cmake?

Comment: In CMake, there are preset ways that describe how a toolchain is to be invoked (compile, link, etc.). So trying to extract the intermediate artifacts can be challenging at times. I'll add my previous comment and this to the answer.